# Converting Visual FoxPro forms to C#.Net Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am creating hundreds of C#.NET forms by reading the VFP source and writing the C#.net by hand currently

The VFP form properties height, width, top, and bottom of all objects are identical to the C#.Net form properties. The font is identical (exception "MS Sans Serif" is changed to "Microsoft Sans Serif" and the font size is the same.

The spacing and size of the objects are different. Enough to make a mess when the objects(labels, textboxes) are close together on the VFP side.

I noticed that these lines in the C#.Net Designer help space things around a bit

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
```

Any suggestions on how to make the new .Net form as identical as possible?

Here is an example of my situation:

[VFP Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZF1U.png)

[C#.Net Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGCdP.png)

Comment: Switch your monitor to 96 DPI (aka 100%) to have a shot at making them the same.  Scaling up is a lot easier than scaling down.

Comment: You are saying "by hand". Then how come you can make such a mess. .Net winforms too has a layout toolbar, and actually is better than VFP's. The VFP form on the image is a very simple one to convert. You can also, instead write a VFP or C# code that would do the conversion for you ( a generator IOW ).

Comment: @HansPassant How can I do this?

Comment: @CetinBasoz When I say by hand I mean I am exporting the VFP form properties and then manually typing in the values into C#.Net's form designer properties

Comment: OK then you might try these 2 options. 1) Use font size 1 less than what VFP uses. 2) Instead of just putting the values you see in VFP, calculate where the adjacent control should be.

Comment: It looks like vfp and WinForm use different unit to measure font: WinForm looks bigger. Did you check Unit property for the font (winForm) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: use WPF, not WIndows Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is the unit used to measure the font size: VFP and WinForm use different units.

[Unit Font MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you choose Font -> **Unit=Pixel** this will fix your problem.

[image: Example]

**The default for WinForm is Point.**

With default value (Point):

[image: Before]

With Pixel value:

[image: After]

Comment: This looks good and my controls no longer overlap! But it makes everything smaller. Is there a point to pixel conversion chart?

Comment: Actually just did a quick look up. The point to pixel conversion is 1.333333333333333
So multiply the point by 1.33 to get the pixels

Comment: @Auios, point to pixel conversion is not constant and calculated based on device capabilities.